# Returning all keys that have the same corresponding value in a dictionary with python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm new to this site, and I have a problem that I need some help with. I am trying to find the highest integer value in a dictionary and the corresponding key and then check if there are other keys with the same value. If there are duplicate values i want to randomly select one of them and return it. As of now the code can find the highest value in the dictionary and return the key, but it returns the same key each time. I'm not able to check for other keys with the same value.

```
def lvl2():
    global aiMove2
    posValueD = {}
    for x in moveList(): #Movelist returns a list of tuples
        m = aiFlip(x) #aiFlip returns an integer
        posValueD[x] = m
    aiMove2 = max(posValueD, key = posValueD.get)
    return aiMove2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the maximum, you can check each key of their values. This comprehension list returns a list of keys where the value associated if the same as `aiMove2`.

```
keys = [x for x,y in posValueD.items() if y == posValueD[aiMove2]]
```

Here's an example in Python shell:

```
>>> a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2}
>>> [x for x,y in a.items() if y == 2]
['c', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
max_value = 0
max_keys = []
for key,value in myDict.iteritems():
  if value > max_value:
    max_value = value
    max_keys = [key]
  elif value == max_value:
    max_keys.append(key)
if max_keys:
  return random.choice(max_keys)
return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use itertools groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
di={'e': 0, 'd': 1, 'g': 2, 'f': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'l': 2, 'i': 1, 'h': 3, 'k': 0, 'j': 1}

groups=[]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(di.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0])), lambda t: t[1]):
    groups.append(list(g))

print(groups)
# [[('c', 3), ('h', 3)], 
   [('b', 2), ('g', 2), ('l', 2)], 
   [('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('i', 1), ('j', 1)], 
   [('e', 0), ('f', 0), ('k', 0)]]
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
print([list(g) for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(di.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0])), 
        lambda t: t[1])])
```

Then just take the first list in the groups list of lists.